# iTerm2: Set tabs to current directory

Tags: iterm2

I use iTerm2 as my Shell on Mac. When programming the most descriptive info of what a certain tab is doing would be the current directory. I looked through all the options but I don't see a way to do it, yet I bet there is one!

How do I change the tab title to be the current directory of the shell? I think there's a way but I don't know what it is.

Comment: The following links were given in a link-only answer, which I am preserving here in case it is deleted by the Review Queue: [solution](http://blog.locut.us/2009/10/30/simple-bash-script-to-name-a-tab-in-iterm/), [reference](https://gist.github.com/phette23/5270658).

Comment: Good thinking, thanks!